# Failed to include c++ librabry in lex

Tags: compiler-construction, lex

I was trying to do some lexical analysis by LEX, and I'd like to include some c++ library in the definition field. Yet, I've tried several times but always got this error message:

```
sample.l:2:23: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

And this is how my code looks like:

```
 %{ #include<iostream> void Print_input(char* yytext){ //function... } %}
```

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: @sepp2k Hi, I am compiling it in linux environment and by the command: flex -o lex.yy.c sample.l  gcc -o sample lex.yy.c -lfl ./sample < sample.txt (the text file is the testing file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're compiling your C++ code as C by using `gcc` - use `g++` instead.

Note that while gcc usually uses the file extension to determine the language, `g++` will compile .c files as C++ even without the `-x` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps.